# Highlighting a word in a DataGridView?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, highlight

In my C# 3.5 Windows Forms application I have a grid (DataGridView). I would like to highlight a word inside some cell, but the grid only allows me to highlight the whole cell.

Is there any tweaks for the grid or any available usercontrol, built on DataGridView, which can highlight a single word inside DataGridView cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution would be to use a `RichTextBox` column in your `DataGridView`. Then you would be able to highlight a single word as well as have complete control over the formatting in the cell. Take a look at this article:

[RichTextBox column in DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView)