# Changing the colour of searched key word in a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have to wrote a `DataGridView` and filled it programmatically.
I want when the user searches the a word for example key and there is cell which contains it (for example its keyword) just highlight the searched word key in keyword not the all keyword or not the cell nor the row.
Here is  the code for filling `DataGridView`:

```
        private void Fill()
    {
        try
        {
            if (dataGridView1 != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 11;
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_ID;
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Family;
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Cellphone;
                dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone1;
                dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone2;
                dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone3;
                dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Fax;
                dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_CompanyName;
                dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Agency;
                dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Brands;
                dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = Resources.Form1_Fill_Address;

                dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_ID;
                dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Family;
                dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Cellphone;
                dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone1;
                dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone2;
                dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone3;
                dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Fax;
                dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_CompanyName;
                dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Agency;
                dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Brands;
                dataGridView1.Columns[10].Name = Resources.Form1_Fill_Address;
            }

            _conn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from contacts ", _conn);
            _conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int i = 0;
            while (reader != null && reader.Read())
            {
                if (dataGridView1 != null)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                }
                if (dataGridView1 != null)
                {
                    var row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];

                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_ID].Value = reader[0].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Family].Value = reader[1].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Cellphone].Value = reader[2].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone1].Value = reader[3].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone2].Value = reader[4].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Phone3].Value = reader[5].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Fax].Value = reader[6].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_CompanyName].Value = reader[7].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Agency].Value = reader[8].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Brands].Value = reader[9].ToString();
                    row.Cells[Resources.Form1_Fill_Address].Value = reader[10].ToString();

                }
                i++;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            _conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

and here is the search code

```
        private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code to search the  alphanumneric Part Number (in Column1 header called "PART NUMBER") and highlihgt the row
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            try
            {

                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    //row.Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                {
                    var t = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                }
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                        row.Cells[1].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[2].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[3].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[4].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[5].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[6].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[6].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[7].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[7].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[8].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[8].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[9].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[9].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                if (row.Cells[10].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
                    row.Cells[10].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use `richtextbox` in your dgv.see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233948/highlighting-a-word-in-a-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

If this search is only depend upon client side loaded data then why don't you suggest to customer use browser search functionality.

If still you have to provide this functionality to customer then why you are going at server side code to do this task.... you can handle this in javascript. 
Following are the example Link which explains about how to access datagridview in javascript.

1. http://www.netomatix.com/development/gridviewclientsideaccess.aspx
2. http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/webdatagrid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with standard .NET controls. 
You can try [Telerik winform suite](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx) or similar, which controls allowing to use HTML formatting to highlight only a part of the text.

Do you really need `DataGridView`? If you use it to display data only, you can also try using `WebBrowser` control and draw an html table there.

You should also refactor your search code:

```
for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
{
   if (row.Cells[i].Value.ToString().Contains(searchTxt.Text))
     row.Cells[i].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: The user wants the simple exe file.
Is there anything to use instead of Datagridview in application??

Comment: @Morteza as I said, if there is no need to select something from the table, use webbrowser control to draw the table

Comment: Would you help me to use webbrowser control.

Comment: @Morteza read about it, find an example, try it and if you still have questions, I ill help you